# hash password in ruby using req.basic_auth(Net::HTTP)

Tags: ruby, authentication, hash, puppet, credentials

I have a puppet custom type which code is as follows:

```
...
payload = 'items.find({"repo":{"$eq":"' + $node_repo + '"}}).include("name","path","property.*")'
uri = URI.parse("#{$node_instance}/api/search/aql")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host,uri.port)
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path)
req["Content-Type"] = "text/plain"
req.basic_auth 'user', 'secret'
req.body = payload
res = http.request(req)
...
```

Since the custom's type content is copied in all puppet agents I don't want any clients to have the node credentials, is there a way to hash the password and pass it to Net::HTTP request?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would it make sense to you to pass the secrets through the catalog? That is sensitive anyway. The type code would just use it like any other parameter.

Comment: Perhaps it makes sense, how can I achieve that?

Comment: The secret and user should be parameters for your type. and passed from hiera. Hiera has an eyaml backend that keeps data encrypted

Comment: You're right cristi, thanks!

Comment: @cristi if you make that an answer I'll totally vote for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make the secret and the user to be parameters for your type.

Hiera has an eyaml backend that keeps data encrypted, so you can pass the password from hiera.

This is an example on how we pass passwords from hiera:

```
foreman::db_password: >
  ENC[PKCS7,MIIBiQYJKoZIhvcNAQcDoIIBejCCAXYCAQAxggEhMIIBHQIBADAFMAACAQAw
  --snip
  ejAKgCACkmEEX/2ijQcTQj9vJf5ytnBlOSYymNbA+/8zcz0dmg==]
```